# Blank output value from Wordress custom admin settings field

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-fields

I've added the example cod shown below. This works like a charm. But I am unable to **output** the saved values on my page.

Using:
`get_option( 'title' )`
appears to have no value, despite the new admin section properly saving a value for it.

I've also tried `get_option( 'title','does not work' )` and confirmed that 'title' is empty, as it's outputting default value of 'does not work'

Here is the code I've added to the function file. All appears fine in admin and saves values as expected. (this is example #2 here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

```
class MySettingsPage
{
    /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', 
            'My Settings', 
            'manage_options', 
            'my-setting-admin', 
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>My Settings</h1>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'my-setting-admin' );
                submit_button();
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'my_option_name', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'setting_section_id', // ID
            'My Custom Settings', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'my-setting-admin' // Page
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            'id_number', // ID
            'ID Number', // Title 
            array( $this, 'id_number_callback' ), // Callback
            'my-setting-admin', // Page
            'setting_section_id' // Section           
        );      

        add_settings_field(
            'title', 
            'Title', 
            array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
            'my-setting-admin', 
            'setting_section_id'
        );      
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();
        if( isset( $input['id_number'] ) )
            $new_input['id_number'] = absint( $input['id_number'] );

        if( isset( $input['title'] ) )
            $new_input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

        return $new_input;
    }

    /** 
     * Print the Section text
     */
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Enter your settings below:';
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function id_number_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="id_number" name="my_option_name[id_number]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['id_number'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['id_number']) : ''
        );
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function title_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['title']) : ''
        );
    }
}

if( is_admin() )
    $my_settings_page = new MySettingsPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options are saved under a single key my_option_name, so you would access the individual options like:

```
$my_options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
echo $my_options['title'];
echo $my_options['id_number'];
```